# смена Data directory в asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Не могу сменить папку поиска звуковых файлов для АТС Asterisk. Ниже рабочая конфигурация:

```
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                     
  /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf

  [directories]
  astetcdir => /etc/asterisk
  astmoddir => /usr/lib64/asterisk/modules
  astvarlibdir => /var/lib/asterisk
  astdbdir => /var/lib/asterisk
  astkeydir => /var/lib/asterisk
  astdatadir => /usr/share/asterisk
  astagidir => /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
  astspooldir => /var/spool/asterisk
  astrundir => /var/run/asterisk
  astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk
```

При изменении адреса папки на astdatadir => /home/username/media/sound asterisk выдает ошибку:

```
× asterisk.service - Open Source PBX and telephony toolkit
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/asterisk.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-03-19 09:21:25 +05; 5s ago
Process: 77869 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/asterisk -f $EXTRAOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 77869 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 5ms

мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Couldn't find manager DBPut in XML documentation
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Couldn't find manager DBDel in XML documentation
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Couldn't find manager DBDel in XML documentation
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Couldn't find manager DBDelTree in XML documentation
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Couldn't find manager DBDelTree in XML documentation
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: PBX UUID: 8b9bcddf-38f5-468a-9b8c-002613610e2b
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 asterisk[77869]: Cannot update type 'declined_message_types' in 
module 'stasis' because it has no existing documentation!
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
мар 19 09:21:25 host-15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Open Source PBX and telephony toolkit.
```

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и подскажет возможные методы её решения.